# exc_bad_access (code=2 address=0xc)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, xcode5.0.1

Got exc_bad_access (code=2 address=0xc) error at following line

```
createMeetUPViewController = [[CreateMeetupViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:createMeetUPViewController animated:YES];
```

While I am trying to navigate from one viewcontroller to next viewcontroller I got this error.Please help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: try debugging the code in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear in the "CreateMeetupViewController".

Comment: Have you got the solutions yet..

Comment: Write property and sythesize for your viewcontroller and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared property and synthesise for view controller and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Did you forget to call the [super loadview] in the loadView of your controller. I did this before, and when I add this to the loadView it worked.